# How to customize the behavior of session scoped bean by current user is Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, authentication, spring-security

Consider following scenario: Spring Security authenticates login data against custom `UserDetailsService`implementation as follows

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        UserProfile profile = users.find(name);
        if (profile.getUsername().equals("admin"))
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        return new User(profile.getUsername(), profile.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
```

If authentication succeeds, I want to create unique `session scoped service` in controller, with customized behavior by valid `UserProfile` object state. I guess best way to do that is to declare the session bean manually in configuration file and somehow *autowire* `UserProfile` or *session owner* to it's constructor, but how that's possible, when `UserProfile` is not even an managed object?

In this case, I want server to create service for authenticated user, which maintains SSH connection to remote host with credentials stored in `UserProfile`

Also, how to restrict a creation of such service just to post login? Is there way to achieve this kind of behavior, or is it actually bad architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SecurityContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) to access the authenticated user for the current request. I think the best approach is to create a singleton Service with a method like this:

```
public UserDetails getCurrentUser() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        return (UserDetails) principal;
    } else {
        //handle not authenticated users
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can autowire and use the service in your controllers.

Comment: Can I add the actual `UserProfile` object to security context and retrieve it same way? I also get the following error when trying to use session scoped bean: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute with name scopedTarget.sessionBean
`

Comment: SecurityContextHolder returns the same object which you returned from your `UserDetailsService`. So you should be able to cast it to `UserProfile` instead of `UserDetails`. The Service in my example should be a singleton and not be session/request scoped. And the exception means that session scoped beans should be `Serializable`.

Comment: Correction: you return `User` from your `UserDetailsService`. That means you cannot cast it to `UserProfile`. Why do you need the `UserProfile` object?

Comment: I got it working as desired by implementing `Serializable`, thank you. I want `service` to have reference to `UserProfile`, because `UserProfile` contains additional data to credentials and `service` is *customized* on creation based on that data. That's why I need *session scoped* service for each user. I.e. `service` maintains and alter it's state based on the `UserProfile`